# react-scripts-ts + vscode breakpoints

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I want to create a new React TypeScript application and be able to use breakpoints in VS Code.

```
create-react-app myapp --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts
```

[Debugging Tests With Create React App using Typescript in VSCode or Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45663364/debugging-tests-with-create-react-app-using-typescript-in-vscode-or-chrome) seems to suggest this config:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "Debug CRA Tests",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts-ts",
        "runtimeArgs": [
          "--inspect-brk",
          "test"
        ],
        "args": [
          "--runInBand",
          "--no-cache",
          "--env=jsdom"
        ],
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "protocol": "inspector",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
      }
    ]
  }
```

When I run this (I'm on Windows) I get a prompt asking what I want to use to open the file. What should I be selecting at this point?